# Forcing response charset in CherryPy

Tags: python, character-encoding, cherrypy

I want to specify the HTTP response charset by modifying the `Content-Type` header. However, it doesn't work.

Here is a short example:

```
#coding=utf-8
import cherrypy

class Website:
    @cherrypy.expose()
    def index(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type']='text/plain; charset=gbk'
        return '。。。'.encode('gbk')

cherrypy.quickstart(Website(),'/',{
    '/': {
        'tools.response_headers.on':True,
    }
})
```

And when I visit that page, the `Content-Type` is changed mysteriously to `text/plain;charset=utf-8`, causing mojibake in the browser.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ncat 127.0.0.1 8080 -C
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CherryPy/7.1.0
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 01:08:13 GMT

。。。^C
```

It seems that CherryPy detect content encoding and override the charset automatically. If so, how can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right. Solved this problem by tampering `cherrypy.response.header_list` directly.

```
#coding=utf-8
import cherrypy

def set_content_type():
    header=(b'Content-Type',cherrypy.response._content_type.encode())

    for ind,(key,_) in enumerate(cherrypy.response.header_list):
        if key.lower()==b'content-type':
            cherrypy.response.header_list[ind]=header
            break
    else:
        cherrypy.response.header_list.append(header)

cherrypy.tools.set_content_type=cherrypy.Tool('on_end_resource',set_content_type)

class Website:
    @cherrypy.expose()
    @cherrypy.tools.set_content_type()
    def index(self):
        cherrypy.response._content_type='text/plain; charset=gbk'
        return '。。。'.encode('gbk')

cherrypy.quickstart(Website(),'/')
```

Comment: You should try setting `tools.encode.encoding` and `tools.decode.encoding` http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/config.html#environments

Comment: well, the website i'm working into is a file-sharing server, which means the encoding varies from file to file. so i can't hard-code the encoding into cherrypy config.

Comment: Cherrypy config may be overridden on class or handler basis. It doesn't have to be global.

Comment: the encoding varies according to the request parameters. for example, `/download?id=1` might be `UTF-8` encoded and `/download?id=2` might be something else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38665815/595220 JFYI you are able to modify headers without additional hooks/tools

Comment: i know, but cherrypy will modify my modified `Content-Type` header back if I change `cherrypy.response.headers` directly in the handler, as my question says.

Answer (score 0):

I had success to set the content-type-charset by setting/manipulate the request header attribute "Accept-Charset".

```
cherrypy.request.headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1"
cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml"
```

The result:

```
>curl -I https://127.0.0.1/url?param=value

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: CherryPy/18.6.0
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 11:54:49 GMT
Content-Length: 288
Set-Cookie: session_id=d28fa46a1a3d901d9502038255ce869b21add5cc; expires=Mon, 10 Aug 2020 12:54:49 GMT; Max-Age=3600; Path=/
```